# Inaccessible item using C++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on C++ project that uses inheritance. I seem to have an error in visual studio in the below file administrator.h. It says that salariedemploye:salary on line 17 is inaccessible and I am not sure why.

Admin.cpp

#include

```
namespace SavitchEmployees
{
    Administrator::Administrator( ):SalariedEmployee(), salary(0)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    Administrator::Administrator(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double theAnnualSalary)
      :SalariedEmployee(theName, theSsn),salary(theAnnualSalary)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }

    void Administrator::inputAdminData()
    {
        cout << " Enter the details of the administrator " << getName() << endl;
        cout << " Enter the admin title" << endl;
        getline(cin, adminTitle);
        cout << " Enter the area of responsibility " << endl;
        getline(cin, workingArea);
        cout << " Enter the immediate supervisor's name " << endl;
        getline(cin, supervisorName);
    }

    void Administrator::outputAdminData()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << getName() << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << adminTitle << endl;
        cout << "Area of responsibility: " << workingArea << endl;
        cout << "Immediate supervisor: " << supervisorName << endl;
    }

    void Administrator::printCheck()
    {
        setNetPay(salary);
        cout << "\n___________________________________\n"
             << "Pay to the order of " << getName() << endl
             << "The sum of" << getNetPay() << "Dollars\n"
             << "______________________________________\n"
             << "Check Stub Not negotiable \n"
             << "Employee Number: " << getSsn() << endl
             << "Salaried Employee(Administrator). Regular Pay: "
             << salary << endl
             << "______________________________________\n";
    }
}
```

admin.h

```
#include <iostream>

#include "salariedemployee.h"
using std::endl;
using std::string;

namespace SavitchEmployees
{
    class Administrator : public SalariedEmployee
    {
        public:
            Administrator();
            Administrator(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double salary);
            double getSalary() const;
            void inputAdminData();
            void outputAdminData();
            void printCheck();
        private:
            string adminTitle;//administrator's title
            string workingArea;//area of responsibility
            string supervisorName;//immediate supervisor
    };
}

#endif
```

SalariedEmployee.cpp

```
namespace SavitchEmployees
{
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee():Employee(),salary(0)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(const string& theName, const string& theNumber, double theWeeklyPay)
      :Employee(theName, theNumber), salary(theWeeklyPay)
    {
        //deliberately empty
    }
    double SalariedEmployee::getSalary() const
    {
        return salary;
    }
    void SalariedEmployee::setSalary(double newSalary)
    {
        salary = newSalary;
    }
    void SalariedEmployee::printCheck()
    {
        setNetPay(salary);
        cout << "\n___________________________________\n"
             << "Pay to the order of " << getName() << endl
             << "The sum of" << getNetPay() << "Dollars\n"
             << "______________________________________\n"
             << "Check Stub NOT NEGOTIABLE \n"
             << "Employee Number: " << getSsn() << endl
             << "Salaried Employee. Regular Pay: "
             << salary << endl
             << "______________________________________\n";
    }
}
```

Salariedemplyee.h

```
#ifndef SALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H
#define SALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H

#include <string>
#include "employee.h"

namespace SavitchEmployees{
    class SalariedEmployee : public Employee{
    public:
        SalariedEmployee();
        SalariedEmployee(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double theWeeklySalary);
        double getSalary() const;
        void setSalary(double newSalary);
        void printCheck();

    private:
        double salary;
    };
}
#endif
```

employee.cpp

```
namespace SavitchEmployees
{
    Employee::Employee():name("No name yet"),ssn("No number yet"),netPay(0){}
    Employee::Employee(const string& theName, const string& theSsn):name(theName),ssn(theSsn),netPay(0){}
    string Employee::getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
    string Employee::getSsn() const
    {
        return ssn;
    }
    double Employee::getNetPay() const
    {
        return netPay;
    }
    void Employee::setName(const string& newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
    void Employee::setSsn(const string& newSsn)
    {
        ssn = newSsn;
    }
    void Employee::setNetPay(double newNetPay)
    {
        netPay = newNetPay;
    }
    void Employee::printCheck() const
    {
        cout << "\nERROR: pringCheck function called for an \n" 
             << "Undifferentiated employee. Aborting the program!\n"
             << "Check with the author of this program about thos bug. \n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your class defined??

Comment: I am not sure where "line 17" is, but I don't believe you can initialize base class members using the initializer. ie. you have to put 'salary = theAnnualSalary' in the body of the Administrator constructor instead of putting 'salar(theAnnualSalary)' in the initializer list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is declared private in `Salariedemplyee.h`. Change it to protected to use it for inheritance.

```
class SalariedEmployee : public Employee{
    public:
        SalariedEmployee();
        SalariedEmployee(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double theWeeklySalary);
        double getSalary() const;
        void setSalary(double newSalary);
        void printCheck();

    private:
        double salary;
    };
```

The second problem is that the value of a member variable can only be set in the initialization list of a constructor that belongs to the same class as the variable. Use the assignment operator instead.

```
Administrator::Administrator(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double theAnnualSalary)
      :SalariedEmployee(theName, theSsn)
    {
        //deliberately empty
        salary = theAnnualSalary;
    }
```

Comment: now it says
error salary is not a non static data member or a base class of class of administrator

Comment: Instead of initializing the variable in the constructor initialization list, use the assignment operator in the method like this:

`Administrator::Administrator(const string& theName, const string& theSsn, double theAnnualSalary)
      :SalariedEmployee(theName, theSsn)
    {
        salary = theAnnualSalary;
    }`

Comment: The constructor initialization list initializes variables before it enters the body of the constructor and the value of a member variable can only be set in the initialization list of a constructor that belongs to the same class as the variable.